# spark parallelize(List(1,2,3,4),2) always partition the list in order?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've run the code below and the result is 37.

```
val z = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,7,4,30,6), 2)
z.aggregate(0)(math.max(_, _), _ + _)
res40: Int = 37
```

It seems that spark partitions the list into 2 lists:[1,2,7] , [4,30,6].

Then I changed the order of 7 and 4 in the list and I got 34.

```
scala> val z = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,4,7,30,6), 2)
z: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[18] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> z.aggregate(0)(math.max(_, _), _ + _)
res11: Int = 34
```

What I want to know is if spark always keeps the order of the elements in the list when partitioning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different concepts here.

- Order of items which is persevered when using `parallelize` and applying transformations which don't require shuffling.
- Order of items during aggregation which is not preserved and is non deterministic. While each partition is aggregated sequentially order of merging partial result is arbitrary.

In general don't depend on the order of values and operations unless you enforce it explicitly (for example by sorting) or you know exactly what you're doing.